# how to decode json that starts with [{ in php

Tags: php, json

SO I've been searching for a while now but I haven't found anything useful. Im interested in decoding a json code like this:

```
[
{"server":"1","available":true},
{"server":"2","available":false},
{"server":"3","available":true},
{"server":"4","available":true}
]
```

I want to decode that using json_decode in php. How can I do that? =)

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Just do it..

Comment: What is wrong ? http://codepad.org/5Eo7vBLx

Comment: Like this http://codepad.org/J3HxU5gt

Comment: See this [visualization](http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=&json=%5B%0D%0A%7B%22server%22%3A%221%22%2C%22available%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%22server%22%3A%222%22%2C%22available%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%22server%22%3A%223%22%2C%22available%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%22server%22%3A%224%22%2C%22available%22%3Atrue%7D%0D%0A%5D) if you are unsure how to traverse over the initial array wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the php native function `json_decode` you will get an structure that matches the json structure.

Use the function like this:

```
$myobject = json_decode('[
                            {"server":"1","available":true},
                            {"server":"2","available":false},
                            {"server":"3","available":true},
                            {"server":"4","available":true}
                         ]');
```

With this code you will have in $myobject this structure:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    'server' => string(1) "1"
    'available' => bool(true)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    'server' => string(1) "2"
    'available' => bool(false)
  }
  [2] =>
  array(2) {
    'server' => string(1) "3"
    'available' => bool(true)
  }
  [3] =>
  array(2) {
    'server' => string(1) "4"
    'available' => bool(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As array of objects:

```
$data = json_decode($rawData);
```

As array of assoc arrays:

```
$data = json_decode($rawData, true);
```

http://php.net/json_decode